# Как растянуть div на всю высоту телефона?

Tags: html, css, height

Как растянуть div на всю высоту телефона? Чтобы при смене разрешения (телефона) высота всегда подстраивалась под размер экрана, его высоту, и при этом чтобы делала снизу отступ в 50px , подскажите пожалуйста, 100vh не робыть у меня почему то, хоть через absolute, без разницы как, заранее спасибо тем кто поможет, а не фигню начнет писать

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста минимальный нерабочий пример

Comment: У вас в коде viewport прописан?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В css есть свойство `min-height`, которое обеспечивает заданную высоту при любых условиях, а так как Вам еще нужно чтобы всегда оставался отступ в 50px, то воспользуемся css-функцией `calc`, в итоге получаем такой код для стиля элемента:

.item {
min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]